# Embedding vs continuous injection?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's algebraic topology, I read the following:

> Let $h: D^k \to S^n$ be an embedding. Then $\tilde{H}_i(S^n \setminus
>  h(D^k)) = 0$ for all $i$.

Here an embedding is a map that is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Would it be correct to replace the word "embedding" by continuous injection?

Because if $h$ is a continuous injection, then $h$ is a continuous bijection onto its image and since $D^k$ is compact and a subspace of the sphere is Hausdorff we get that $h$ is a homeomorphism, so $h$ is an embedding?

Comment: For completeness, here is an example of a continuous injection that is not a topological embedding. Consider $T^2 = \mathbb{R}^2 /\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to T^2$ given by $f(x) = \pi x$ (you could take any irrational number instead of $\pi$). This is a continuous injection but not an embedding since every open subset of $f(x)$ contains points of the form $f(x')$ where $|x-x'|$ is arbitrarily large, which is not the case for the metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact so your argument doesn't hold to show $f$ is an embedding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, yes you are correct -- although (I'm pointing it out but you probably already know it) *in general* the two notions aren't equivalent.